# Android insert date into datetime SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime

I'm working with a sqlite-android which contains a table with a field "datetime",

I'm trying to insert a value in that table with :

```
 ContentValues cvv = new ContentValues();

            cvv.put("viatge_id",v.getId());
            ....
            cvv.put("time",s.getDate());
```

s.getDate returns a Date Element. but it seems i can't use the last instruction that I show you

Comment: Which of [SQLite's date types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just [convert](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) the Date instance to ms and then insert the long into your DB?

So

```
cvv.put("time",s.getDate().getTime());
```